# NSDictionary containing NSNull*

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing a code to parse a json response in the following way:

```
 NSDictionary* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
 if (jsonArray == nil) {
            // returns empty array
            return layouts;
 }
 NSDictionary* sections = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"section"];
 for (NSDictionary* section in sections) {
```

Unfortunately, "section" sometimes is empty and I end up with sections being a __NSArrayI * which contains one element - NSNull * . This causes the for loop to fail with an exception. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why is it returning an NSArray when you expect an NSDictionary?  Might need to see some more code.

Comment: NS**Dictionary** *json**Array** is very confusing, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to have a cleanup method on an NSDictionary extension that helped me tackle this. Basically the method iterated through all the keys in the dictionary and removed any values that matched NSNull(), returning a "clean" dictionary and arrays. The trick is that you must also recurse through nested dictionaries. So, **in pseudocode**, it would look something like this:

```
func cleanup() -> NSDictionary {
    let newDictionary = NSDictionary()
    for key in dictionary.copy {
        if dictionary[key] is NSDictionary {
            newDictionary[key] = dictionary[key].cleanup()
        } else if dictionary[key] is NSArray {
            newDictionary[key] = dictionary[key].filter( $0 != NSNull() )
        } else if dictionary[key] !=  NSNull() {
            newDictionary[key] = dictionary[key]
        }
    return newDictionary
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a Swift answer to an Obj-C question.

Comment: The logic is still the same, and I've flagged the code as pseudocode. Chances are the code won't even run in swift to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this function to your parser and call it

```
- (id)objectForKeyNotNull:(NSString*)key inDict:(NSDictionary*)map {
    id object = [map objectForKey:key];
    if (object == [NSNull null])
        return nil;
      else
        return object;
}
```

You then can call it like this in your parser:

```
 // will set myObject to nil if it is null in the JSON response
 myObject = [self objectForKeyNotNull:@"keyNameInDict" inDict:yourDictionary];
```

Comment: The idea is good but instead of adding it to `self`, you should add it to `NSDictionary` via a category.

Comment: This doesn't let you use subscript notation for accessing values.